# How to add third-party libraries in the build?

Tags: webpack, config

I use webpack and my question is how to add third-party libraries in the build?
For example I have folders with fonts and images. What the commands I need to add to my webpack config file to these folders could appear in production folder (from developer folder)?

For example I have `<link href="libs/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` in my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can just require that from your main entry file and webpack will do the rest.

`import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';`

Without knowing much else about your setup I would say this is your best starting point. Also you can then remove that from your HTML. If you are looking to have a separate style sheet you can look at the [Extract Text Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) for more details.